# Memory management in C++ mixed mode application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, memory, memory-management

I'v a mixed mode application which is x32. So there only 2G of memory available. The application processes some large data and allocates about 1.5G in unmanaged heap. Then it releases allocated unmanaged memory without leaks. But the next step is to process about 1.5G in managed mode. And the application crashed when trying to add element in List when about 200M of managed memory allocated. As I suppose, the unmanaged heap manager grabs memory for 1.5G, allocates objects in it, then deallocated objects but don't release heap memory to be accessable to managed heap manager. How managed and unmanaged memory managers share process's memory? How can I tackle with such problem?

Here a sample code which throws exception when trying to allocate managed memory after allocating and releasing unmanaged code. It must be compiled in x32. Why does this happen?

```
            int size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 2 / 10;

            char* * cppArray = new char*[size];

            for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            {
                char *str = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(str, "AAAAAAAAAA"); 
                cppArray[i] = str;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            {
                char* str = cppArray[i];
                free(str);
            }

            delete[] cppArray;

            List<String^>^ pArray = gcnew List<String^>();

            size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 2 / 7 / 2 / 2;

            for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            {
                pArray->Add(gcnew String("AAAAAAAAAA" + i.ToString()));
            }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have to consider the way managed code allocates the memory. If you are using a list (that has a node for each element) you have to consider the overhead of that list (not to mention some other matadata that C# might have). So for a list node you store a value and a pointer to the next list node , this means that if you want 1.5GB of data you might end up with another 1.5GB of pointers totalling 3 GB. Also there is heap memory header that adds a bit of overhead also.

Comment: what happens  if you use managed heap before unmanaged? are you able to allocate memory for the list?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I know well how managed code allocates memory and consider it. Application handles two sets of data. One set in unmanaged mode due to compartibility issues. And another set in managed mode using new code. We refactoring application to be managed. But now it mixed. And in managed code it will be using about 1G-1.5G at all with all managed overheads.

Comment: But the problem is different. It crashes when only about 200M of managed occupied. I use Jetbrains dotMemory and it shows 90M of unmanaged and overral about 200M of managed (using all generations and large object heap) at the moment of crash.

Comment: High memory usage for 32bit is not a good idea. I accidentially compiled my .net code with "32bit preferred" and I could only allocate ~1GB (also in chunks) before I got out of memory, despite that the limit should be ~2GB for 32Bit, especially since it was not one large block. Can you perhaps create the memory chunks in unmanaged code and use them in managed?

Comment: Yes 32bit is bad. But due to project shedule we have not enough time now to seriously refactor the application. We use new managed code to tackle with unicode data. And mix this code with old unmanaged one which quite complicated. So the best option for me is to know can I move free memory from unmanaged memory manager to managed heap. If it's not possible then I will consider using two separate processes or deep refactoring with another time estimates.

Comment: Are there any articles about relations between managed and unmanaged memory management in mixed mode applications? Why when we allocate and then release 1.5 of unmanaged memory it becomes inaccessible for managed heap?

Comment: Can we shrink unmanaged hep if it has a lot of free memory at the end?

Comment: For Windows, you can flag an x32 exe LargeAddressAware so on a 32bit OS (maybe needing a boot flag as well) you get 3GB instead of the usual 2GB and running that 32bit exe in 64 bit Windows you get 4GB.  It sounds like you should be able to do a better job with the 1.5GB you described.  But just increasing what you can use might cover the problem more easily.

Comment: @JSF  I'll second the `LargeAddressAware` advice, but on 64-bit, typically you can get as high as ~3.7GB before crashes.  That's 3.7GB total Virtual Address Space for the entire process (that's Virtual Bytes counter from Perfmon, or Virtual Size from Process Explorer).  Also mind that you don't fragment the Large Object Heap.  And note that **managed memory is only a subset of the process' total Virtual Address Space**.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, whatever is once malloc'ed stays mallaoc'ed. The reason is the way `malloc()` gets its memory from the OS, namely increasing the heap max address. So to release it again you have to be sure there are no more references to any address there or you get a segment fault.

Now there is a way around this that ***might*** work namely [`mmap()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) find an allocator that use `mmap()`, or whatever its called in MS speak. Make sure it can release it again with something like `munmap()`.

Allocate your data in the memmapped addresses and be sure no reference to it is left before you unmap it.

ps.
Also like @JSF said compile with LargeAddressAware and enable 3GB on your OS.
And be sure you have at least 4GB RAM even on 32 bit systems, the OS uses some of it that is not accessible to users. Even if *each* program only have access to 3GB that still add up to more than 3GB really fast.